# How do I implement role based access control for a DynamoDB Adapter? Conflicting Types Issue

Tags: typescript, next.js, typeerror, next-auth

I am trying to implement RBAC, role based access control, within NextJS (next v14.1.0) with AuthJS (nest-auth v5.0.0-beta.5) in Typescript while using the DynamoDB Adapter (@auth/dynamodb-adapter v1.2.0).

I have the DynamoDB Adapter implemented, and it writes user and session information to DynamoDB without issue.

I would like to be able to add a 'role' field to my User in order to handle RBAC within AuthJS.

But, I have run into Type issues extending the JWT and Session User information to include a 'role' field.

*! I have no real understanding of NextJS' or Typescript's type extension or data modeling approaches and need guidance around them !*

I have the following jwt and session callbacks defined:

```
  callbacks: {
    jwt({ token, user }) {
      return {
        ...token,
        role: user.role,
      }
    },

    session({ session, token }) {
      return {
        ...session,
        user: {
          ...session.user,
          role: token ? token.role : session.user.role,
        }
      }
    },

    authorized({ request, auth }) {
      const { pathname } = request.nextUrl
      if (
        pathname === "/abc" || 
        pathname === "/xyz"
        ) 
        return !!auth
      return true
    },
  },
```

The `token` in `session({ session, token }) {` results in this error:

```
Property 'token' does not exist on type '({ session: Session; user: AdapterUser; } | { session: Session; token: JWT; }) & { newSession: any; trigger?: "update" | undefined; }'.
```

I also have a type issue with the adapter property

```
  adapter: DynamoDBAdapter(client,
    {
      tableName: process.env.NEXT_AUTH_USER_TABLE_NAME 
    }),
```

With `adapter` resulting in this error

```
Type 'AdapterUser' is not assignable to type 'Awaitable\<AdapterUser\>'.
Property 'role' is missing in type 'import("/home/next/node_modules/@auth/core/adapters").AdapterUser' but required in type 'import("/home/next/node_modules/next-auth/node_modules/@auth/core/adapters").AdapterUser'.ts(2322)
next-auth.d.ts(8, 9): 'role' is declared here.
index.d.ts(161, 5): The expected type comes from property 'adapter' which is declared here on type 'NextAuthConfig'
```

For reference this is also my mess of a `next-auth.d.ts` file

```
import 'next-auth';
import { DefaultUser } from 'next-auth';
declare module 'next-auth' {
    interface Session {
        user?: DefaultUser & { id: string; role: string };
    }
    interface User extends DefaultUser {
        role: string;
    }
    interface AdapterUser extends User {      
        id: string;
        email: string;
        emailVerified: Date | null;
        role: string;
    }
}
```

---

I want to be able to initialize and reference a role: string property in my user for AuthJS for the purpose of implementing Role Based Access Control.

I expected to be able to output the role, I experienced a Type error after successful compilation when running `npm run build`.

```
 ✓ Compiled successfully
   Linting and checking validity of types  ...Failed to compile.

./auth.ts:158:3
Type error: Type 'import("/home/next/node_modules/@auth/core/adapters").Adapter' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/next/node_modules/next-auth/node_modules/@auth/core/adapters").Adapter'.
```